# Tried Removing bootstrap and now cannot change any CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

While trying to uninstall Bootstrap I created a mess. My application.css no longer has an effect on my app. What do I do?

These are the steps I took to create this issue:

Remove `require bootstrap` from application.css
Remove `require bootstrap` from application.js
Remove bootstrap link in header on application.html.erb
Ran `bundle exec rake assets:clean` 1000 times

After all that Bootstrap has /not / been removed and now no CSS changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Look at any page from your application and see what CSS files are bundled with it. Chances are you might have some external stylesheet (maybe bootstrap from a cdn) linked and it's overriding your local css since it's positioned lower down the page.

Or you removed this line

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
```

and you no longer are including any of the css from your asset folder.

Comment: hm, I removed all metioned of bootstrap. That line is still in place (`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`). I found that if I run `rake assets:precompile`, everything is fine... still looking for a way not to have to run that command everytime  make a css change...

Comment: check the asset pipeline settings. You might have turned something off.